# How do i make a button that can count when a user clicks it?

Tags: html, button, counter

I am new to coding and I would like to make a button that increment the count by 1 when a user clicks on it. I also would like to know how can I restrict it to be clicked only once. It is similar to the facebook `like` button but I want to create my custom button that would do the same thing but will just be shown in my website.

Comment: show your work till now. Then only one would be able to help you

Comment: Please, specify your operating system and platform!

Comment: take a look into javascript or jquery

Comment: before your comments, i didn't know what language to use. Thank You TopGunCoder i will look into javascript or jquery.

Comment: @Claudio i am using joomla and i can't find any plugins available for this specific function. This led me to hard code it and learn it at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing, using jQuery. The HTML part would be as under

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

The jQuery code, that would be added to the `<script>` tag in `<head>` section.

```
var click = "1"; // set the variable
$('button').click(function () { // click on button
   $(this).text('Clicked ' + click + ' times'); // write the variable value in it
   click ++; // increment the variable
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/jRXBr/4/ (For testing; as per Pippin's suggestion)

To disable it, use

```
$('button').click(function () { // click on button
   $(this).prop('disabled', true); // set its disabled property to true
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/jRXBr/1/ (For testing)

You can test the codes, using the fiddles that I have created, and you will understand how they work! :)

Comment: Thank You! this is very useful. I will try to make the button with this guide!

Comment: `click += 1;` should be corrected to `click ++;`. The current linked Fiddle just concatenates and gives odd values like 'clicked 1..clicked 11..clicked111...times' **See [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jRXBr/3/) for correct jQuery**.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Perfect. For some reason they didn't accept the edit to your answer I made and now editing is disabled for my account =/ At least the comment went through.